# Young's experiment

Tags: visible-light

Does the interposition of the glass slide, which has a refractive index different from that of air, alter the wavelength emitted by the laser? Does this impact young's experiment?

Comment: where is the glass slide?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that putting glass on slits impact on interference pattern and destroy it or not?